# Self-learning computer science and coding

Tags: reference-request

I want to learn more computer science in theory and practice. However, I really don't know where to find more practical exercises in languages like Java or Python. I feel like the best way I could learn all the concepts and ideas is by coding on my own. I would thank very much for any suggestion of websites, books or small interesting projects that could help me develop this skills.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately this kind of question is not well-suited to this site.  The question is inherently subjective (everyone will have their own favorite answer), and it's very broad.  We want questions that admit a single answer.  Book recommendations generally don't work well here.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/160917 and https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ and http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  Also, questions about programming or coding are off-topic here; this site is for technical questions about computer science.  See our [help].

Comment: for general CS stuff that doesnt fit on the site, try dropping by [chat]